Создание Spring проекта в intellij community
Решил попробовать спринг, создал проект через spring initializr (maven, java), открыл его в intellij (community), и в итоге он отказывается его признавать: в xml файле dependencies выделены красным (он не может их найти) и в основном файле (.java, который создается по дефолту в spring проекте) все импорты и аннотации: @SpringBootApplication, @Springapplication и т.д. тоже.
Не могли бы вы написать решение этой проблемы, как открыть spring проект в community версии, может ultimate надо использовать?
Если надо прикрепить скрины, напишите.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Обычно просто File->Open (можно еще через File->New->Project from Existing Sources) и выбрать в проводнике папку с .pom файлом, IDE даже их подсвечивает. Если не открывает, значит проблемы где-то в окружении. Тогда стоит проверить JDK в настройках нужной версии, проверить maven, сделать File->Invalidate Caches, может даже файлы IDE повреждены (иногда помогает переустановка).

@Alex Krass, сделал как ты написал, проблема осталась, удалил ненужные зависимости и осталось просто spring-starter-web, в pom.xml intellij все нравится, но вот в DemoApplication.java я не могу пользоваться функциями спринга и х он уже выделяет красным, может просто попробую создать maven проект и все сам импортирую

@CurS Максимум могу еще предположить, что maven что-то не выкачал из репозиториев или может прав не хватает? Добавил для примера как обычно выглядит создание проекта в обоих вариантах в IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.3 (Community Edition). Проблему это не решит, но хотя бы будете знать, что с точки зрения создания нового проекта вы не допускали ошибок. Этот способ использовался не только мной, поэтому маловероятно, что это просто мой компьютер содержит что-то уже особенное и установленное.

Для примера покажу, как выглядит создание чистого проекта через initializr и пустой maven проект. Так же крайне важно при редактировании pom файла не забывать применять изменения через Load Maven Changes.
Скорее всего это не поможет, так как проблема по описанию не в создании проекта, а где-то еще. Но пускай будет для справки.
Initializr

Беру чистый проект с одной зависимостью, чтобы можно было еще запустить и посмотреть. Добавлена только одна зависимость, чтобы результат запуска посмотреть. Далее Generate и распаковать полученный архив.



В Intellij Idea пункт File->Open и папка с файлами из архива.



По хорошему этого должно быть достаточно и приложение запустится. Для теста добавлен RestController, чтобы после запуска при переходе на locahost:8080 увидеть результат.


Maven

Новый проект Maven

Перенесены секции parent, dependencies и build, обязательно нажать Load Maven Changes.

Проект должен запуститься, для теста добавлен RestController




Спасибо, проблему решило, создал самостоятельно мавен проект, скопировал pom.xml у тебя, добавил все нужные файлы и запустил сервер - все работает. Свои maven проекты идеально запускаются, именно с initializr постоянно ошибки, хз в чем проблема, может pom файл не подходит, что-то не добавлено, не разбираюсь в этом вообще, но главное что проблема решена
